# Relational Algebra: Natural join with NULL value

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra, natural-join

Table 1

```
Customer  id  city 
John       1   LA
Nancy      2   NULL
```

Table 2

```
Customer  $ in the pocket 
John       20
Nancy      30
```

I am wondering what happen if `Table 1` **natural join** with `Table 2`? My guess is that the result would be 4 attributes and both John and Nancy will appear.

But my friend told me that only John will appear, Nancy won't because there is a `null` value.

Comment: joins happens on two attributes and if you joins using Customer( which will be default) then your friend is wrong :)

Comment: To figure it out, just rewrite the NATURAL JOIN as regular INNER EQUIJOIN, using the same rules that NATURAL JOIN uses. Given the relations in your example, that would be an equijoin on the `Customer` attribute. (The NULL value in the city attribute doesn't matter, since the other relation doesn't have an attribute named `city`.) A NATURAL JOIN will use all attributes that have the same name. If the second relation also had a attribute named `city`, that would be the same as an INNER EQUIJOIN on both the `Customer` and `city` attributes.

Comment: For natural join, are we only joining if we have matched common-attribute, (in this case, is the Customer field)?

Comment: @spencer7593, so if the common attribute doesn't contain `null`, then it would be fine?

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as saying that a "NATURAL JOIN" would be fine. Outside of academia, we never use NATURAL JOIN. (All we need is for someone to add a column to table2 named `city`, and our query that was working gets broken.) When I encounter a NATURAL JOIN, for me to figure out what that is really doing, I need to look through all of the columns in both tables, and find all matches. And while I do that, I quietly  curse the developer who saved himself all the time by typing "`NATURAL`" instead of "`ON a.customer = b.customer`", so I could spend twenty times more time to figure it out.

Comment: Using "NATURAL JOIN" also essentially prohibits us from adding common housekeeping columns with the same name (datetime row added, datetime row modified, user/actor that modified the row), as well as prohibiting naming any anonymous surrogate primary key columns with the same name (`id`). It basically forces us to adopt wonky naming conventions for columns so we don't inadvertently create columns of the same name, while forcing us to use the same column name if we want to do a equijoin operation. The drawbacks of NATURAL JOIN far outweigh any perceived benefits.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, whenever you see a NATURAL JOIN, just know that it's an EQUIJOIN on a set of columns (attributes) that it's up to you to figure out. You need to look at the table definitions to figure out *all* of the columns in the two tables have the same name. You can't stop at just the first match; you have to verify that there aren't any other column names that match.

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page.

Answer (score 2):

In the case above, your friend is wrong, you are right!

Let's see a case where it would be otherwise:

> Table 'Customer'

```
Id Name   AccNo
1  John    44
2  Nancy  NULL
```

> Table 'Account'

```
AccNo $_in_Pocket
44       20
45       30
```

Here, with a natural join, we would get all attributes for John but Nancy would be missing from the results.

Comment: You don't have to format your answer using HTML tags and entities, instead use proper Stackoverflow answer formatting